# Does model.train() put every thing in train mode in pytorch even sub-networks?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I wrote a neural network in PyTorch, which uses ResNet as feature generator, and it is fined tuned with the whole network.

My model consists of Resnet and several layers that I added to it. My question is:

When I call model.train(), Does it put ResNet in train mode or I should call train on it separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By the look of it](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.train), if you call [`train()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train) on a module, it will call `train()` recursively on all children. So `model.train()` - `model` being the model containing the Resnet - will suffice.